# How to format external hard drive with Mac OS Extended (Journaled) without a Mac computer?

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas, format, airport

I want to connect a Seagate external hard drive to my Airport Extreme usb port but I don't have a Mac computer to format it using the required Mac OS Extended file system.

Is there a way to do this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

OS X uses the Hierarchical File System Plus (HFS+), aka Mac OS Extended filesystem. GParted can manage HFS+ partitions, but you've got to have some other packages installed in Linux for this to work: *hfsplus*, *hfsprogs* and *hfsutils*.

You can easily install all of these packages on an Ubuntu live USB without writing anything to your computer's hard drive.